# Is there a R package for computing intraindividual Gamma correlations?

Tags: r, package, correlation, hmisc, gamma

im searching a r package that enables me to compute Goodman and Kruskal's gamma correlations within each subject. I have 2 variables with 16 items each, which I would like to correlate per subject.

So far I used the Hmisc package and the rcorr.cens() function. However, the function creates an correlation overall subject and I failed to adapt the code to get a correlation for each subject... Thats how I tried so far....

````
        ```Gamma_correlation <- dataframe %>% 
           group_by(Subject) %>% 
           rcorr.cens(dataframe$Variable_1,                          
                      dataframe$Variable_2, 
                      outx = TRUE)[2]```
````

Comment: a [mcve] would be very  helpful.  You can probably achieve what you want with `rcorr.cens` suitably wrapped in a for loop ...

Comment: thanks for your advise. I was also thinking about creating a for loop... but I wanted to check first if there is any package I havent thought about, that would resolve the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly achieve this by removing the `dataframe$` and just keeping the variable names. `Hmisc` also seems to mask the summarize function of the `dplyr`, so you can put the `rcorr.cens` chunk in `dplyr::summarize()`.